# Flask.request object not available in Jinja2 template

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am expecting to handle a url like:
http://localhost/say?something=hello

and in my template I have

```
{% for a in request.args %}
    {{a}} = {{ request.args[a]}} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

However this results in
**'jinja2.exceptions.undefinederror'**

I am able to "work around" the problem by explicitly passing the args to the template in a variable, but obviously that's just a bloated hack. Any help would be appreciated.

*Versions:*
Python       3.7.7
Flask        1.1.2
Jinja2       2.11.2

---

I created a new project that reproduces the error. It does nothing except create a template and passes no variables to it.

```
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import Template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return Template('{{request.args}}').render()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Following is the traceback I get on the error:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-06-02 11:28:44,660] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/dmg/PycharmProjects/TemplateTest/app.py", line 9, in hello_world
    return Template('{{request.args}}').render()
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
  File "/Users/dmg/Documents/Dev/TemplateTest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 471, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'request' is undefined
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2020 11:28:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: you might want to do this ```{{a =  request.args[a]}}```

Comment: Works for me too. Can you post the stacktrace? Are you sure you didn't unintentionally define "request" elsewhere override the Flask.request object? Try just printing the output of {{request.args}} somewhere and it should return an ImmutableDictionary.

Comment: @RyanH I am new to python. Using PyCharm as an IDE. I will try to figure out how to produce the stack trace. Meanwhile: When I template {{request}} I get nothing back.  When I template {{request.args}} I get "'request' is undefined"  I will also try spinning up a brand new project and see if it happens in a basically empty project. Thanks!

Comment: Include the `request` in `from flask import Flask, request`

Comment: @RyanH Many moons later I figured out that I needed to create my template environment like this:  templateEnv=app.create_jinja_environment().  In my original code for some reason I created an environment with templateEnv=Environment(), and in my test application it appears I didn't create an environment at all.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the "standard" flask functions and objects, you need to create the jinja template environment via app.create_jinja_environment().

That function initializes the environment globals with
url_for, get_flashed_messages, request, session and g